# Node.js Web Settings HTTP Server

Tags: node.js

Sorry about the vague title, I'm not entirely sure what to call what I'm looking for.

Basically I'm building an application and want to be able to change the settings of the application from anywhere via a website. The server must be capable of updating its contents as the applications data changes and grows.

Is there any pre-built and easy to use solution out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to handle that kind of task. You have to store settings in database, I recommend using redis/memcached because they're really fast, much cheaper performance than using reading files or using other databases.

First, you must have a static initial `settings.json` file, and check at bootstrapping if redis contain `app_settings` record yet or not. If not, persist that static json to redis, else skip.

Whenever you change settings via website, you have to update the record in redis (and update to file json at the same time asynchronously if needed).